# Template Validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I have various form elements - which have been laid out in HTML, I now need to validate the entries in each of the form field. Some require integers of a specific length, others require `HH:MM:SS` type entry validation.
After several attempts, and tying myself in knots, I wonder are there templates that assist in entering a variable (name) defining the input and returning a false statement or an overall alert to indicate error in the form.
I have html code...but feel I should be able, with assistance create the valid JavaScript for "posting".

Any assistance gratefully received.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>My test table for input</title>
</head>
<html>
<table>
<tr><td>Number*</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Number" size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>User ID*</td>
<td><input type="text" name="UserID" size="4" maxlength="4"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Current Date (YYYY-MM-DD)*</td>
<td><input type="text" name="CurrentDate" size="10" maxlength="10"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Curent time (HH:MM:SS)*</td>
<td><input type="text" name="CurrentTime" size="8" maxlength="8"/></td>
</table>
</html>​
```

Comment: can you use `input type="date"` and `input type="time"`?

Comment: HI there, yes I can changer them to suit.

Comment: When I try to run validation on the "parameter" I have set up, the validation is ignored. Simply think I have the if / else true / false all back to front and cannot sort this out in my head.

Comment: Validation has not only to be the text input, but the type of value - be it integer of certain length / format or numbers of certain length or format.
I am going to remove all the javascript I have coded and try to start again. Thanks